# iphone: create provisional build then send to someone else

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-provisioning, udid

how can i create a provisional build and then send it to my work colleague so they can view it on their iphone?

I have there udid number if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the udid to your devices in the provisioning portal, then generate a new provisioning profile that contains that device.  Use the profile to build an adhoc distribution in XCode and send the resulting app with a copy of the provisioning profile to your client.  They will drag both into itunes and will be able to install the app on said device.

Comment: the thing is i am programming for the iphone 3.1.2 and my work colleague has an iphone 4 which has 4.0.1. Will my build run on his iphone?

Comment: As long as you set the deployment target to the lowest common denominator, ie 3.1.2 then yeah it will run fine.

Comment: hi, ive just upgraded to the same standard that they have. now i have added the udid to the device in the provisioning portal. then i generated a new profisioning profile that contains that device. I dont know what to do from there? what do you mean by USE the profile to build an adhoc distibution in xcode?

Comment: You must drag the provisioning profile into XCode, then select it as your code signing identity in the distribution configuration build properties. The iPhone provisioning portal gives detailed instructions on how to create an adhoc build.